# PATH still affected by Anaconda after uninstalling

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, python, path

When I run echo $PATH in terminal (macOS), it returns `/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. I have uninstalled anaconda and both my opt directory and .bash_profile are empty. When I run the which python command it returns : `/usr/local/bin/python`. In similar questions the problem is solved by removing the anaconda directory from the PATH environment variable but my `~/.bash_profile` is empty.

Python is running fine in terminal but I'm guessing PATH runs through the empty directories where Anaconda files were located first? I am guessing this is not optimal and can create problems in the future?

**Gordon Davisson's solution:**

I am running zsh. Here's what I found in my z.profile :

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Here's what I found in .zshrc (when I tried to edit it said I "don't own the file" and should duplicate it to edit):

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

I wasn't able to locate `~/.zlogin`, `~/.zshenv` or `~/.profile`. But here's what I found in `paths.d` (not sure what the file "100-rvictl" is):

```
Last login: Mon Sep  6 17:21:00 on ttys001
me@mahmouds-mbp-2 ~ % /etc/paths.d/100-rvictl ; exit;
/etc/paths.d/100-rvictl: line 1: /Library/Apple/usr/bin: is a directory
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why don't you just edit the $PATH variable to remove the path that no longer eixsts?

Comment: Having nonexistent directories in your `PATH` isn't really a problem, but it might be good to track down where it's coming from anyway. First, are you running bash or zsh? Try `ps $$` to find out. If it's bash, check `~/.bash_login` and `~/.bashrc`. If it's zsh, check `~/.zprofile`, `~/.zlogin`, `~/.zshenv`, and `~/.zshrc`. In either case, check `~/.profile` and also `/etc/paths` and any files in `/etc/paths.d/`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I have edited my question with the results of what you have advised. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the leftover `PATH` entry is coming from your `~/.zshrc` file. The entire "conda initialize" section (from `# >>> conda initialize >>>` to `# <<< conda initialize <<<`) should be removed. If that's the only thing in the file, you can just delete the entire file. But if there are other things there you should edit it, and it'd be best to fix its ownership first.

Fixing file ownership: You can take ownership of the file with:

```
sudo chown "$UID" ~/.zshrc
```

...but there might be other files with the same problem, so I'd recommend running `ls -l ~` to list all the files in your home folder, and apply that fix to any others that aren't owned by you. For folders, use `sudo chown -R "$UID" ~/foldername` to get their contents as well.

BTW, the ownership problem is likely a result of some installer or setup script running as root (i.e. with `sudo`) rather than under your user ID, and therefore creating files owned by root rather than you.

Oh, and about that `/etc/paths.d/100-rvictl` file: it looks like you double-clicked it, which tried to run it as a script, which didn't really work (it's not a script). But from the contents, it's not related and shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. I deleted what I found in the '.zshrc'file but the it hasn't solved the path problem yet. I have found more "condo initialise" sections in 2 other files '.xonshrc' and '.tcshrc'. They are also locked but I guess I can solve this by using the  'sudo chown -R "$UID" ~/foldername' command to own them. The "condo initialise" sections are their only contents, should I delete them or do you recommend to just edit the sections out of them?

Comment: If that's all that's in them, just delete them. Those are initialization files for other shells. Apparently the Anaconda installer put them there just in case you happen to use those shells -- but you don't, so they're doubly irrelevant.